# Insert data from one table to other using select statement and avoid duplicate data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Database: Oracle

I want to insert data from table 1 to table 2 but the catch is, primary key of table 2 is the combination of first 4 letters and last 4 numbers of the primary key of table 1.

For example:

> Table 1 - primary key : abcd12349887/abcd22339887/abcder019987

In this case even if the primary key of table 1 is different, but when I extract the 1st 4 and last 4 chars, the output will be same abcd9887

So, when I use select to insert data, I get error of duplicate PK in table 2.

What I want is if the data of the PK is already present then don't add that record.

Here's my complete stored procedure:

```
 INSERT INTO CPIPRODUCTFAMILIE
 (productfamilieid, rapport, mesh, mesh_uitbreiding, productlabelid)
 (SELECT DISTINCT            (CONCAT(SUBSTR(p.productnummer,1,4),SUBSTR(p.productnummer,8,4)))      
                 productnummer, 
   ps.rapport, ps.mesh, ps.mesh_uitbreiding, ps.productlabelid 
  FROM productspecificatie ps, productgroep pg, 
   product p left join cpiproductfamilie cpf
    on (CONCAT(SUBSTR(p.productnummer,1,4),SUBSTR(p.productnummer,8,4))) =                            cpf.productfamilieid
  WHERE p.productnummer = ps.productnummer
  AND p.productgroepid = pg.productgroepid
    AND cpf.productfamilieid IS NULL
   AND pg.productietype = 'P'

   **AND p.ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM product
   GROUP BY (CONCAT(SUBSTR(productnummer,1,4),SUBSTR(productnummer,8,4))))**

   AND (CONCAT(SUBSTR(p.productnummer,1,2),SUBSTR(p.productnummer,8,4))) not in 
   (select productfamilieid from cpiproductfamilie));
```

The highlighted section seems to be wrong, and because of this the data is not picking up.

Please help

Comment: your indexes in the `substr` function are wrong, for last 4 characters use `SUBSTR(p.productnummer,9,4)` [SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14ea7/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
p.productnummer IN (SELECT MAX(productnummer) FROM product
    GROUP BY (CONCAT(SUBSTR(productnummer,1,4),SUBSTR(productnummer,8,4))))
```

Comment: How this will determine that the latest productnummer will be used? As we don't have any column (like datetime) to get the latest row

Comment: Order by rowid will not ensure that you will get the latest product number as specified in your query if the number in primary key abcd12349887 is incremental sequence max(productnummer) will return you the latest entry for that product.